# Correct usage sqlalchemy pools with pgbouncer

Tags: sqlalchemy, pgbouncer

there!

I use `PgBouncer` with `Sqlalchemy` for getting connections.

For my understanding, I would like to clarify the following points:

1. I use the sqlalchemy default pool (`QueuePool`) and take connections from my pgbouncer. After the transaction is completed, is the connection returned to the `"lazy"` connection storage on my side (`sqlalchemy`) or directly to the `pgbouncer pool`?
2. If I use `QueuePool` with `pool_size=5` parameters and create an engine for `pgbouncer` pool, does `pgbouncer` allocate these 5 connections at once, or are the connections given on demand?
3. If I remove the connection pooling (using `NullPool`) and also create an engine for `pgbouncer`, does this mean that after exiting the transaction context, the connection is closed and a new one will be created already inside `pgbouncer` at the next request?
4. Which of these approaches is more correct in the context of using `sqlalchemy + pgbouncer`?

With connections I work like this:

```py
async with async_session() as connect:
      yield connect
      await connect.commit()
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't need in-app connection pool if you use pgbouncer, you can either use NullPool+pgbouncer of QueuePool + `use_lifo=True` flag to use LIFO Queue which should reuse old connections first. I am not entirely sure if using both pgbouncer + in-app connection pool would be beneficial or harmful though.

Here's a relevant documentation link: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/pooling.html

Also for automatic transaction commit you could use `sessionmaker.begin()`:

```py
async with async_sessinomaker.begin() as session:
    ...
```